# Discrepency in number of files transferred in Teracopy

Tags: windows-7, usb-flash-drive, file-transfer, file-management, teracopy

Over the past few days, I've been using Teracopy to transfer over a large number of files and folders from a small flash-drive (well, 32gb) ,  to an external hard-drive (4tb).

However, I noticed that after the files were copied over, and after I used the 'Verify File Copying Operation"-option, Teracopy, in the same window, displayed two different file-counts for the number of files that were transferred over. This reflected in the screenshot that is appended right here:

[image: number of files discrepency in teracopy]

On the left side, the number read "2617 files" (this only appeared after the 'Verify' was completed, mind you) and was the correct number of files that were transferred over. 
But, on the right side, within the interior of the "copy from" progress-bar, the number read "2629 files". (Incidentally, there were DOZENS UPON DOZENS of folders within the original 32gb flash-drive that was copied over. )

The 'files and folders' property dialog window for the original-32gb-flash-drive's contents is appended here:

[image: 'files and folders' property dialog window for the original-32gb-flash-drive's contents]

If you could explain to me why this discrepency is appearing within Teracopy, I would be appreciative.

---

Ah, and also, the specs for my computer are, briefly, Windows 7 64bit Home Premium installed on a Dell Inspiron Laptop Model N5110 with Intel i3-2.20Ghz CPU, and 8.00 GB of RAM.

Likewise, my version of Teracopy is, according to the ABOUT dialog box, TeraCopy 2.27

Comment: @psycogeek Errr... I think you might want to re-phrase that a little. But, what I did was: (1)loaded a first windows-explorer window to display the 'copy to'-directory'; (2)loaded a second windows-explorer window to display the 'copy from'-directory'; (3)right-clicked the folder to be copied, and selected TERACOPY; (4)in the resulting Teracopy-copy-dialog, I selected 'copy-to-intended-copyto-directory'.

Comment: Your probably right, I use fastcopy way more often  . That method used would be odd for me to use a combination of right click (terra)copy then to use  its own GUI, sort of half of each method.   My norm would be to use all context menu  copy (terra) paste methods, or to use the gui (rare) only for all of the selections.    So what about the destination files ammount, shown the same way (properties) you have shown the original folder location? You certannly have something weird going on here , i have never seen.

Comment: @psycogeek Yes,the 'file counts + file sizes' in the 'destination-folder properties' was identical to the 'file counts + file sizes' in the 'original-folder properties'.